# How to tell what went wrong with the JUnit test?

Tags: java, testing, junit, case

I have to fix my code based on the JUnit test but I'm not sure how to tell what went wrong?

For example this function of the test code resulted in an error when I ran it

```
@Test
    public void lastValidDay() {
        DayOfWeek dow = new DayOfWeek(12, 31, 2099);
        assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Thursday") == 0);
        assertTrue(dow.getNumericDayOfWeek() == 5);
    }
```

Not sure how to change it so it runs smoothly though? Here is my class where these different JUnits are being tested. This is the class I must change so all the tests run smoothly.

```
public class DayOfWeek1 {
    int myMonth, myDayOfMonth, myYear, myAdjustment, numericDayOfWeek;
    /*
     * @param what the date was
     */
    public DayOfWeek1(int month, int dayOfMonth, int  year){
        myMonth = month;
        myDayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
        myYear = year;
    }
    /*
     * @return the numeric day of the week
     */
    public int getNumericDayOfWeek(){
        if(myMonth==1){
            myAdjustment = 1;
            if(myYear%4==0){
                myAdjustment=0;
            }
        }
        if(myMonth==2){
            myAdjustment = 4;
            if(myYear%4==0){
                myAdjustment=3;
            }
        }
        if(myMonth==3){
            myAdjustment = 4;
        }
        if(myMonth==4){
            myAdjustment = 0;
        }
        if(myMonth==5){
            myAdjustment = 2;
        }
        if(myMonth==6){
            myAdjustment = 5;
        }
        if(myMonth==7){
            myAdjustment = 0;
        }
        if(myMonth==8){
            myAdjustment = 3;
        }
        if(myMonth==9){
            myAdjustment = 6;
        }
        if(myMonth==10){
            myAdjustment = 1;
        }
        if(myMonth==11){
            myAdjustment = 4;
        }
        if(myMonth==12){
            myAdjustment = 6;
        }
        int fourDivides = myYear / 4;
        numericDayOfWeek = myAdjustment + myDayOfMonth + (myYear-1900) + fourDivides; 
        return numericDayOfWeek;

    }
    /*
     * returns what day of the week it was
     */
     public String getDayOfWeek(){
         if(numericDayOfWeek==0){
             return "Saturday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==1){
             return "Sunday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==2){
             return "Monday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==3){
             return "Tuesday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==4){
            return "Wednesday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==5){
            return "Thursday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==6){
             return "Friday";
         }
         else{
             return "NO_VALUE";
         }
     }
     /*
      * @return the month in an int
      */
     public int getMonth(){
         return myMonth;
     }
     /*
      * @return the month in a string
      */
     public String getMonthString(){
         if(myMonth==1){
             return "January";
         }
         if(myMonth==2){
             return "February";
         }
         if(myMonth==3){
             return "March";
         }
         if(myMonth==4){
             return "April";
         }
         if(myMonth==5){
             return "May";
         }
         if(myMonth==6){
             return "June";
         }
         if(myMonth==7){
             return "July";
         }
         if(myMonth==8){
             return "August";
         }
         if(myMonth==9){
             return "September";
         }
         if(myMonth==10){
             return "October";
         }
         if(myMonth==11){
             return "November";
         }
         if(myMonth==12){
             return "December";
         }
         else{
             return "NO_VALUE";
         }
     }
     /*
      * @return what day of the month it was
      */
     public int getDayOfMonth(){
         return myDayOfMonth;
     }
     /*
      * @return what year it was
      */
     public int getYear(){
         return myYear;
     }

}
```

Any tips on figuring out what exactly it is in my code that is making the errors go off?

Comment: The assertion should tell you that the expected value did not match the actual value. It will also tell you what each of those are. Just backtrace (maybe with debugger) and figure out where the actual value came from.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are calling `getDayOfWeek()` before `getNumbericDayOfWeek()`. In your constructor you don't initialize `numericDayOfWeek` so it gets a default value of `0` (all un-initialized primitive types do).

```
public DayOfWeek1(int month, int dayOfMonth, int  year){
    myMonth = month;
    myDayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
    myYear = year;
}
```

You then call

```
assertTrue(dow.getDayOfWeek().compareTo("Thursday") == 0);
```

which will return

```
 public String getDayOfWeek(){
     if(numericDayOfWeek==0){
         return "Saturday";
     }
```

the value `"Saturday"` which when `compareTo("Thursday")` does not return `0` and so your test fails.

You need to call `getNumericDayOfWeek()` first to set the `numericDayOfWeek` field to its true semantic value first.

---

As to the actual question

> Any tips on figuring out what exactly it is in my code that is making
>   the errors go off?

the assert statement would have told you that the condition was false. From there, your first instinct should be to leanr what `dow.getDayOfWeek()` returned because it wasn't equal to `"Thursday"`. One way to figure this out is to do

```
assertEquals("Thursday", dow.getDayOfWeek());
```

It will right away tell you that the expected and actual are different and what their values are. You would see that `dow.getDayOfWeek()` returned `"Saturday"` and you could then see that `numericDayOfWeek` had a value of `0`, and so on.

Comment: I can't change the test class though, only my own

Comment: @WergAsdfwer Then call `getNumbericDayOfWeek()` at the end of your constructor so that it is always set.

Comment: I changed my constructor to this but I am still getting the same errors; public DayOfWeek1(int month, int dayOfMonth, int  year){
  myMonth = month;
  myDayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
  myYear = year;
  getNumericDayOfWeek();
 }

Comment: @WergAsdfwer That's because your `getNumericDayOfWeek` calculation is incorrect. That's the point of unit testing. To find out that it happens and why. Write your own unit tests.

Comment: I cant write my own unit tests, we are using the ones the professor gave us. And I have no clue what could be wrong with my getNumericDayOfWeek class, it seems fine

Comment: @WergAsdfwer You can't write your own unit tests for the your assignment, but you can still write them for yourself. As for your method, why don't you try calculating it yourself? Your month is 12, so adjustment is 6, 2099/4 is 524 (integer division). `6 + 31 + (2099-1900) + 524 = 760`

Comment: Yea I did see that, I changed the last lines of that section to: int remainderSeven = numericDayOfWeek % 7;
  return remainderSeven;

Comment: @WergAsdfwer Why are you returning the remainder when the method is called `getNumbericDayOfWeek()`. **Also your other method is checking the value of the field `numericDayOfWeek`, so shouldn't you be modifying that?**

Comment: This is from the assignment that tells you how to do the calculation: "Compute the remainder of the sum of step 2, when divided by 7. The
remainder gives the day of the week, where Saturday is 0, Sunday is 1, etc"

Comment: @WergAsdfwer Ok and what do you think you should do with that result? Don't you think you should assign it to something and reuse it late?